# Input type mismatch java

Tags: java, input, types, mismatch

I am running into an error where my config file which will be at the bottom of the code, is passing in an integer, but java is throwing an input type mismatch.   Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
 public class World implements Runnable{

String fileName;
Tile[][] map;
Monster[] monArray;
int width,height, damage;
int hitPoints;
int x_coor, y_coor;
Avatar avatar;
double radius, torch;
World world;

 public World(String inFileName){
this.fileName = inFileName;

//Create all the tiles

try {
    Config config = new Config();
    //create the scanner in order to read the file parameters
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    //Get the height and width of the map
    this.width = scanner.nextInt();
    this.height  = scanner.nextInt();
    //get player starting location

    int x_coor = scanner.nextInt();
    int y_coor = scanner.nextInt();
    //get the player's starting HP
    this.hitPoints = scanner.nextInt();
    //get the player's starting damage
    damage = scanner.nextInt();
    //get starting torch size
    radius = scanner.nextInt();
    Avatar avatar = new Avatar(x_coor,y_coor, hitPoints, damage, radius);
    this.avatar = avatar;
    //create the map with dimensionts
    Tile[][] map = new Tile[width][height];
    //set global map
    this.map = map;
    //set world
    this.world = world; 
    //testing
    //System.out.println("Width is: " +width);
    //System.out.println("Height is: " + height);
    StdDraw.setCanvasSize(width* config.getSize(), height* config.getSize());
    StdDraw.setXscale(0,width * config.getSize());
    StdDraw.setYscale(0,height * config.getSize());
    //print out the design of the map for testing purposes
    for(int i = height -1 ; i >=0; i--){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < width ; j++){
            map[j][i] = new Tile(scanner.next());
            //System.out.println("Tile number:" + i + "," + j + "Has been created");

        }
        System.out.println();

    }
    //getting the information about the monsters
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        //get the character code
        String code = scanner.next();
        //get the x_coor
        int x = scanner.nextInt();
        //get the y_coor
        int y = scanner.nextInt();
        //get the monsters hitpoints
        int hitPoints = scanner.nextInt();
        //get the monster damage amount
        int damage = scanner.nextInt();
        //get the amount of time it sleeps
        int sleepMs = scanner.nextInt();
        //Print out monster stats
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.println("Monster Type: " + code);
        System.out.println("Monster Damage: " + damage);
        Monster monster = new Monster(this,code,x,y,hitPoints,damage,sleepMs);
        Thread thread = new Thread(monster);
        thread.start();

    }
```

This is the config file that gives me all the information

```
 30 20
 11 2 20 3 100.0
 L L L L L G G G L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L
 L F L G L S G G G G L L L L L L L L L L L L G G L L L L L L
 L F F G S L S G G G L L L L L M M M L L L G G G F L F F M L
 L F F G G S G G G L L L L L F F F G L L L G G G G G F F M L
 L L L F G G G G G G G L L G G G G G L L L L L G G G F F F L
 L L L G G G G G F G G G G G G L L L L L L L F G L L G F L L
 L L L L G G F F G G G G G S L S L L L L G G F G G G G L L L
 L L L L L G G G G G G L G S L L S L L L G F F G G G G L L L
 L L L G G G L G G G G G G S L G S L L L G F F G L L B L L L
 L L L G L G L G G G L M G G G G L G G G G G G L L L B L L L
 L L M G L L L G G G L L M M G G F F G G G G G L L L G G L L
 L M M L L L L G G G L L L L G G F G G G G G L L G G G G L L
 M M M L L G G G G G G L L L G G G G G M M M L G G G G G L L
 M M S S S L B L L G G L G G G G G G G L L L L G G F F F L L
 L M S B S L B L L L L L G G G G G G G G L M M M G F F L L L
 L L S B B B B L L G G G G G G L L G G G G G G G G F F L L L
 L L S B S L L L F G G L G G L L L G G L G G G G G G L L L L
 L L S S S L L L F F G G G L L L L L L L L G G G G G L L L L
 L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L
 L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L

 SK  3   3   10  3 1000
 OR  6   19  8   2 750
 BA  20  10  4   1 500
 SL  25  16  6   2 1250
```

Comment: while(scanner.hasNextLine()) to  while(scanner.hasNext()) . . try that i could be wrong

Comment: you define radius as a `double` and then you do `radius= scanner.nextInt();`shouldnt that be `radius = scanner.nextDouble();`

Comment: Side note on code quality: unless you intended to create a spaghetti-code monster that will become un-maintainable (well, "will", already is) ... I recommend you to study "Clean Code" by Robert Martin. And apply the techniques suggested in there. Otherwise you will spent most of your time hunting down strange bugs; and you never know what breaks when you try to add a new feature or change something.